# attempting to get a smooth slide effect by looping a jquery animate left on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-animate

I am attempting to animate a horizontal slide using animate left in a loop on mouse over and ending it on mouseleave. [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/uF7mX/1/) is a jsfiddle example of what I have so far.

The loop is working but the animation slows between iterations. What am I getting wrong? Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Code also included below:

```
 <div id="holder">
        <ul class="box_holder">
            <li class="box"></li>
            <li class="box"></li>
            <li class="box"></li>
            <li class="box"></li>
            <li class="box"></li>
            <li class="box"></li>
            <li class="box"></li>
            <li class="box"></li>
            <li class="box"></li>
            <li class="box"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="left"></div>
</div>

<script>
function scrollList(){
    $("ul").animate({
        "left" : "-=30px"
    }, 1000,scrollList);
}

$(".left").hover(function(){
    scrollList("left");
},
function(){
    $("ul").stop();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, check your open/close tags.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better approach would be the target animation to be the maximum left value and the speed of the animation to be based on the number of boxes you have. Also, use 'linear' easing for the animation.
 Something like this:

```
function scrollList(){
    var boxes = $('.box').length;
    $("ul").animate({
        "left" : "-=" + 30*boxes
    }, 700 * boxes, "linear", scrollList);
}

$(".left").hover(function(){
    scrollList("left");
},
function(){
    $("ul").stop();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uF7mX/2/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [docs for the animation function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). The easing specifies how your animation is timed. The default setting doesn't fit your needs in this case - I would suggest to try the `linear` version.